# Question Answered on a Different site in the Network

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, bounty

I came across a question that clearly should have been posted on the Database Administrators Stack Exchange.  I would have voted to close this question, however it had a bounty which meant I was not allowed to do so.  This question had the same question on the DBA stack exchange with an answer.  From what I can see, it does not have a duplicate question within the stack overflow network.  I answered the question citing the other question and quoting the answer.

Did I handle this correctly?  If not, how should I handle/have handled this?

Comment: This is just my opinion, and I don't know if the community has a particular stance on it, but I think that what you did was a good solution. Many people search Stack Overflow specifically for their issues, and even though the question clearly is on topic there, it still may have enough to do with programming to be on topic here. This allows a person who is searching either site specifically to find their answer. The only thing you might consider is making your answer a community wiki. That way it's obvious that you aren't just copying the answer to get rep or recognition.

Comment: It really depends on how on topic it should be for SO. If the question was actually off topic and should only be on DBA you were in the wrong in my opinion. If, however, the question was in the grey area between the two sites what you did was fine.

Comment: I think making your answer a community wiki would be fair. Additionally, don't forget to mention the original author name.

Comment: @DavyM just as a sidenote: CW answer still get you badges and bounties. So even if not for the rep gained from votes, the bounty rep would still pass to OP.

Comment: It was completely off topic.  The question was about why an attempt to drop a schema in MySQL wasn't working.